# What is the preferred Lift way to handle conditional content in a template?

Tags: scala, lift

What is the preferred Lift way to handle conditional content in a template?

As a concrete example, let's imagine the common construct of an "Add to My Favorites" type button.  If not in your favorites, there is a button to click to add it.  If already in your favorites, there is a button to remove it.  Something like this:

```
<div class="lift:MySnippet">

  <!-- other stuff -->

  <div class="favorite">
    <form id="doFavorite" class="lift:MySnippet.favorite?form=post">
      <input type="submit" value="Add to Favorites" />
    </form>
    <form id="doUnfavorite" class="lift:MySnippet.unfavorite?form=post">
      <input type="submit" value="Remove from favorites" />
    </form>
  </div>

  <!-- other stuff -->

</div>
```

I don't see an obvious way in the snippet (via either binding or CSS transformers) to conditionally keep one form vs the other based on the appropriate "favorited" state.

Coming from a Java/SpringMVC/JSP background, this would be solved with a simple `<c:choose>` statement, but with as much time as I've spent trying to figure this out, I can only assume I am going about this completely backwards…

Thanks in advance, Lift gurus!

Comment: Along the lines of what Dylan said, but just to clarify. Lift's template contain no logic, all the logic resides on snippets. On a side note, for this functionality, I'd use ajaxButton instead of a regular form, you can see the definition on [github](https://github.com/lift/framework/blob/master/web/webkit/src/main/scala/net/liftweb/http/SHtml.scala). And finally, you will get many more answers if you post your questions on the [Lift mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/liftweb) Most Lift developers don't come to SO

Comment: @fmpwizard I think I got too carried away with my example instead of the heart of my real question.  What I was really after was in this type of scenario is the "Lift" way to 1. put all conditional content in the template and then hide it from the snippet or 2. use a container html element and dynamically generate the conditional html from the snippet.  #1 "feels" right to me, but I don't want to go against the Lift tide!  (Also, thanks for the heads up about the mailing list!)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't claim to be a lift guru, but here's two options that seem reasonable to me:

Have one snippet, a la `DoOrUndoFavorite`, and within that snippet you would check the favorited state for the user and render one or the other (`if(favorited){...} else{...}`) form.

**or**

Keep your snippets as they are, and within each snippet's render code, return a `Nil` as the `NodeSeq` for your binding if that snippet should not render.

Comment: Thanks!  I will look into these options.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this post from the above mentioned lift mailing list demonstrates conditional html :

[https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!searchin/liftweb/conditional$20view/liftweb/CQG-wTx_qkc/pbD6PURwbksJ](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!searchin/liftweb/conditional%2420view/liftweb/CQG-wTx_qkc/pbD6PURwbksJ)

make sure to click "show quoted text" to see the relevant reply, here is a quote, just in case:

```
>On Oct 18, 10:05 pm, "Jason Anderson" < jla...@gmail.com> wrote:
> Ah, that makes sense
>
> perhaps the simple/*.html pages in the lift example should be
> changed to use this style of rendering rather than embedding the 
> templates in the snippet?
>
> it would also give you a chance to implement/test out that attribute
> binding for links you mentioned in another reply
>
> On 10/18/07, David Pollak < d...@athena.com> wrote:
>
>
>
> > Jason,
>
> > <lift:snippet type="...">
> > <cond:true>
> > <table> 
> > <tr><td><f:name/></td></tr>
> > </table>
> > </cond:true>
>
> > <cond:false>
> > Hey, there are no users... sorry
> > </cond:false>
> > </lift:snippet>
>
> > You can represent both cases (or even multiple cases) in the XHTML
> > and let the snippet decide which subsection of the XHTML to use. 
> > Given Scala's amazing XML handling capaibilities, it's a single line
> > of Scala code to select the code block:
>
> > val trueBlock = (xhtml \ "true").filter(_.prefix == "cond").headOr 
> > (<span>Template not defined</span>)
>
> > It does make the template look a little ugly, but no worse than an
> > ERB or JSP block looks.
>
> > Also, the <cond:.../> is a convention I've been using, but you can 
> > use any tags (e.g., <users:some> & <users:none>)
>
> > Thanks,
>
> > David*
```